# Is $[a,\infty )$ closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In standard topology, of course $[a,\infty )$ is closed since its complement is open. But I don't know how to prove closeness of $[a,\infty )$ in Real Analysis using just the definition of closeness, i.e.,

Definition: A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be closed provided that if ${\{a_n}\}$ is a sequence in $S$ that converges to a number $a$, then the limit a also belongs to $S$.

It is easy to prove for $[a,b]$. But I don't know how to prove $[a,\infty )$ is closed.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean $[a,\infty]$? Extended real line?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Thank you

Comment: @MattSamuel BTW, may I ask what's the difference between $\infty]$ and $\infty)$? Thanks

Comment: @Vim $\infty]$ means the interval includes $\infty$. This doesn't make sense unless $\infty$ is part of the set. When we add the points $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to the real numbers, this is called the extended real line.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you.  So is that to say the extended real line includes "infinitely large quantity" ?

Comment: @Vim yes. I've only seen it used in measure theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Suppose a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $[a,\infty)$ converges to a limit $L \notin [a,\infty)$. Write $L = a - \epsilon$ and find a contradiction.